# automatic jquery alert on post resquest from python

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, python

I want to create a page **index.php** that should automatically (without refreshing) pop an alert containing post data each time a post request is made to **post.php**.
The scripts **send.py** and **post.php** work perfectly and return each time `{"key":"i"}`, but **index.php** shows nothing. What's the problem with my code?

**Index.php**

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "post.php",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(data){
    alert(data.key);
  }
});
```

**post.php**

```
<?php echo json_encode($_POST); ?>
```

**send.py**

```
import urllib2, urllib
import time
for i in range(3):
    mydata=[('key',i)]
    mydata=urllib.urlencode(mydata)
    path='http://localhost/post.php'
    req=urllib2.Request(path, mydata)
    req.add_header("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    page=urllib2.urlopen(req).read()
    print page
    time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: Do you have somewhere to persist this data between the POST and GET? As it stands right now, when the POST completes, the data will be thrown away and there won't be anything for the GET to get.

Comment: No, so what should I add in order to keep the GET checking for available post data?

Comment: A database. Set up like this, there's no way to send data from the POST to the GET. The POST is done and over with long before the GET happens (or they're on different threads, or otherwise not shared at all).

Comment: I actually wanted to do it without having to use a database but looks like it is impossible, thanks.

Comment: You could maybe come up with some in-memory solution, if you only care about having a single value stored at a time, but I would recommend some actual datastore (perhaps memcached or redis, if you have small payloads).